# sed: make everything on matched lines lowercase to the right of a pattern

Tags: sed

What I'm trying to do is to use sed to make all characters lowercase to the right of a pattern, but only on lines that contain another pattern.

Let's say I want to make everything to the right of /directory/ lowercase on lines that contain the word sillyduck.

Before:

```
sillyduck MOO/WORD/directory/THIS/FILE.TXT
sillyduck another/directory/with/a/file.DOC
#sillyduck MOO/WORD/directory/ANOTHER/FILE
sillygoose MOO/WORD/directory/THIS/FILE.TXT
SILLYDUCK MOO/WORD/DIRECTORY/THIS/FILE.TXT
sillyduck QUACK/DUCK/directory/You/Get/The/Idea.doc
```

After:

```
sillyduck MOO/WORD/directory/this/file.txt
sillyduck another/directory/with/a/file.doc
#sillyduck MOO/WORD/directory/another/file
sillygoose MOO/WORD/directory/THIS/FILE.TXT
SILLYDUCK MOO/WORD/DIRECTORY/THIS/FILE.TXT
sillyduck QUACK/DUCK/directory/you/get/the/idea.doc
```

What would be the best way to go about doing this? I would like to stick to sed for the solution.

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: You should have included several lines of sample input with the word "directory" twice on a line in various contexts. Most potential solutions  probably won't do what you want in some of those cases.

Comment: Apologies on that. Anything after the first directory on a line should be made lowercase.

Before:

    sillyduck MOO/WORD/directory/THIS/directory/FILE.TXT

After:

    sillyduck MOO/WORD/directory/this/directory/file.txt

Comment: You should add that to your sample input/output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given the new info in your comment:

```
$ echo 'sillyduck MOO/WORD/directory/THIS/directory/FILE.TXT' |
    sed '/sillyduck/ s~/directory/.*~\L&~'
sillyduck MOO/WORD/directory/this/directory/file.txt
```